# Different CSS Padding in HTML Form

Tags: html, css

[Form Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK0qZ.png)

I'm trying to create a CSS form and my "form-row" section has different padding than the rest of my fields.

```
<div class="form-body">
                <div class="frm-row">
                <div class="section colm colm6">
                    <label for="names" class="field-label"></label>
                    <label class="field prepend-icon">
                        <input type="text" name="names" id="names" class="gui-input" placeholder="Name">
                        <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>  
                    </label>
                <!-- end section -->
                </div><!-- end row -->

                <div class="section colm colm6">
                    <label for="email" class="field-label"></label>
                    <label class="field prepend-icon">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="gui-input" placeholder="Email Address">
                        <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>  
                    </label>
                </div><!-- end section -->
                </div>

                <div class="section">
                    <label for="telephone" class="field-label"></label>
                    <label class="field prepend-icon">
                        <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="gui-input" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i></span>  
                    </label>
                </div><!-- end section -->                 

                <div class="section">
                    <label for="address" class="field-label"></label>
                    <label class="field prepend-icon">
                        <input type="address" name="address" id="autocomplete" class="gui-input" placeholder="Address">
                        <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>  
                    </label>
                </div><!-- end section -->         

                    <button type="submit" class="button" style="width:100%"><b>Submit</b></button>

            </div><!-- end .form-body section -->
```

I've tried targeting several elements in my stylesheet but I can't seem to make them all have the same spacing. I'm wondering if this might be an issue with the row floating left:

```
.frm-row .colm{min-height:0px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;position:relative;float:left;}
```

EDIT:

Here are the other relevant parts of CSS that I missed, my mistake:

```
.smart-forms .section{margin-bottom:5px;}
.smart-forms .frm-row{margin:0 -10px;}
.smart-forms .frm-row:before,
.smart-forms .frm-row:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0;}
.smart-forms .frm-row:after{clear:both;}
.smart-forms .frm-row .colm{min-height:0px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;position:relative;float:left;}
.smart-forms .frm-row .colm6{width:50%;}
.smart-forms .frm-row .colm{width:100%;float:none;padding:0px;}
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your CSS?

Comment: the mistake might comme from ether .frm-row, .colm or .colm6. we need the rest of the css to help you. Or can you do a snippet code that look like the picture.

Comment: @eikiprog Sorry, I missed some lines of CSS. Still a bit new to everything. I've edited the main question and added the relevant lines.

Comment: Do you use a css framework to acheive that design, i test your css with the html you give us but that nowhere the same as the picture :D

Comment: @EikiProg I probably should have set it up this way from the start, but here's a [JSFiddle with all the code](https://jsfiddle.net/mw0268/p3ujjd4p/#&togetherjs=8l2dwCeG0v)

Comment: If it's the vertical spacing between the first 2 row, just add .smart-forms .frm-row .section{margin-bottom:0;}

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I spent so much time looking for something that wasn't there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your padding for field-icon.It will work.